# Clarification about differentiable functions on manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry

I have a question regarding differentiable functions over $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$-manifolds (for clarification, I mean real-valued function, that is $f:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$)

So, let's suppose $M$ is a n-manifold. It is known that $M$ can be embedded on $R^{2n}$. 
Let's suppose we have f a differentiable function on $M$(as a subspace of $R^{2n}$).

> Does f admit an extension to an open set $U$, so that $M\subset U$?(Assume $M$ compact)

I have a feeling that the answer is no, thus a function that might not be differentiable in any open set around $M$ could still be differentiable in $M$, but a haven't been able to find such an example.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks everyone!

Comment: In the compact setting, thanks to the tubular neighbor theorem ( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tubular_neighborhood ) it is actually true.

Comment: If $M$ is a closed submanifold of some $\Bbb{R}^p$, and $f: M \to \Bbb{R}$ is smooth, then yes it can be extended to an open set in $\Bbb{R}^p$ containing $M$. To prove this, trying proving (using properties of submanifolds) that you can do so,locally; i.e around every point $x\in M$, there is an open subset $U_x$ of $\Bbb{R}^p$ and a map $F_x : U_x \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $F_x|_{M \cap U_x} = f|_{M \cap U_x}$. Then,let $U$ be the union of all $U_x$, and use a partition on unity of $M$ subordinate to the open cover $\{U_x\}_{x \in M}$ to patch together all the local constructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve such an extension in an elementary way. For each point $p\in M$, there is a neighborhood $U_p\subset\Bbb R^{2n}$ and a smooth extension $\tilde f_p$ of $f$ to $U_p$. (For example, there are local coordinates $x$ on $U_p$ in which $M\cap U_p = \{(x^1,\dots,x^{2n}): x^{n+1} = \dots = x^{2n} = 0\}$ and then we set $\tilde f_p(x) = f(x^1,\dots,x^n)$.) Now take a partition of unity $\{\phi_p\}$ subordinate to the open covering $\{U_p\}$ and let $\tilde f = \sum \phi_p\tilde f_p$.

(When $M$ is compact you can first reduce to a finite subcovering, if you like. And if $M$ is not compact, you can reduce to a countable subcovering and then take the partition of unity.)